# Android : Download images and mp3 audio from server

Tags: android

I want to download MP3 audio and images from server.File is downloaded but not goes into sd card folder.Below my code is correct or not or something wrong in  downloading on store into sd card folder.How to work with download media files and save into sd card folder.Thanks in advanced.

Here is my MP3 download code.

```
public void DownLoadAudioFile(final String mp3Url , final String strImageName) {
        new AsyncTask<String, String, String>()
        {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
                int count;
                try
                {
                    f_url[0] = mp3Url;
                    URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
                    URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                    conection.connect();
                    // Get Music file length
                    int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();
                    Log.e("lenghtOfFile "," = " + lenghtOfFile);
                    // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
                    if(lenghtOfFile > 0)
                    {
                        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),10*1024);
                        // Output stream to write file in SD card
                        newFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + File.separator + "classnkk_audio");
                        File file = new File(newFolder, strImageName);
                        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                        long total = 0;
                        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1)
                        {
                            total += count;
                            publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));
                            output.write(data, 0, count);
                        }

                        output.flush();
                        output.close();
                        input.close();
                        Log.e("Audio Files", "DownLoad ans save in SD card Fully !!!");
                        Log.e("======================"," DownloadMusicfromInternet ======================");
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                }
                return null;
            }
        }.execute();
    }
```

and here is my image download code

```
void download_PngFile(String fileUrl, String ImageName) {

        try {
            URL ImgUrl = new URL(fileUrl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) ImgUrl.openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            int lenghtOfImage_File = conn.getContentLength();
            Log.e("lenghtOfImage_File "," = "+lenghtOfImage_File);

            if(lenghtOfImage_File > 0)
            {
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize = 1;
                Bitmap imagenObtenida = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(conn.getInputStream(), null, options);
                File file = new File(newFolder, ImageName);

                if (file.exists()) file.delete();
                try
                {
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    imagenObtenida.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                    int imagenObtenidaW = imagenObtenida.getWidth();
                    int imagenObtenidaH = imagenObtenida.getHeight();
                    Log.e("imagenObtenidaW " ," = +" + imagenObtenidaW + " imagenObtenidaH = " + imagenObtenidaH);

                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



if (imageName.endsWith(mp3_Pattern))
                    {
                        str_DownLoadUrl = namespace + "/DownloadFile/FileName/"+imageName;
                        DownLoadAudioFile(str_DownLoadUrl ,imageName);
                        strDownLoadStatus = "1";
                        dbhelper.update_DownLoadStatus(imageName, strDownLoadStatus);
                    }
                    if (imageName.endsWith(png_Pattern) || imageName.endsWith(jpg_pattern) || imageName.endsWith(bmp_pattern) || imageName.endsWith(gif_pattern) || imageName.endsWith(jpeg_pattern))
                    {
                        str_DownLoadUrl = namespace + "/DownloadFile/FileName/" + imageName;
                        download_PngFile(str_DownLoadUrl,imageName);
                        strDownLoadStatus = "1";
                        dbhelper.update_DownLoadStatus(imageName, strDownLoadStatus);
                    }
```

Comment: Does it create a directory properly in your sd card?

Comment: Yeah, I have already create directory in sd card on the Login Page.It created properly in sd card.